# R: plyr/ddply and adjusted means

Tags: r, plyr, mean

I have a dataset that has several hundred variables with hundreds of observations.  Each observation has a unique identifier, and is associated with one of approximately 50 groups.  It looks like so (the variables I'm not concerned about have been ignored below):

```
 ID     Group     Score
  1        10       400
  2        11       473
  3        12       293
  4        13       382
  5        14       283
  6        11       348
  7        11       645
  8        13       423
  9        10       434
 10        10       124
```

etc.

I would like to calculate an adjusted mean for each observation that needs to use the N-count for each Group, the sum of Scores for that Group, as well as the means for the Scores of each group.  (So, in the example above, the N-count for Group 11 is three, the sum is 1466, and the mean is 488.67, and I would use these numbers only on IDs 2, 6, and 7).

I've been fiddling with plyr, and am able to extract the n-counts and means as follows (accounting for missing Scores and Group values):

```
new_data <- ddply(main_data, "Group", N = sum(!is.na(Scores)), mean = mean(Scores, na.rm = TRUE).
```

I'm stuck, though, on how to get the sum of the scores for a particular group, and then how to calculate the adjusted means either within the main_data set or a new dataset.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using the dplyr package, you would probably need something like `group_by(mydf, Group) %>% summarise(num = n(), total = sum(Score), mean = sum(Score) / n())`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `plyr` way.

```
ddply(main_data, .(Group), summarize, N = sum(!is.na(Score)), mean = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE), total = sum(Score))

  Group N     mean total
1    10 3 319.3333   958
2    11 3 488.6667  1466
3    12 1 293.0000   293
4    13 2 402.5000   805
5    14 1 283.0000   283
```

Check out the `dplyr` package.

```
main_data %>% group_by(Group) %>% summarize(n = n(), mean = mean(Score, na.rm=TRUE), total = sum(Score))

Source: local data frame [5 x 4]

  Group n     mean total
1    10 3 319.3333   958
2    11 3 488.6667  1466
3    12 1 293.0000   293
4    13 2 402.5000   805
5    14 1 283.0000   283
```